# How to get numeric value from text field?

Tags: objective-c, text, integer, uitextfield

in Xcode 7.2 I set Keyboard type as Number Pad for UITextField. But when I try to read the value from the text field means app get crashed. I used following code to read the integer value.

```
int amount = [_amount.text intValue];
```

I googled and found same as suggested solution. Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting ?

Comment: will you specify the reason for app crash. Put the error

Comment: I dont know but the below solution works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this it will works for me.

```
int amount = [_amount.text integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int amount = [self.amount.text integerValue];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!